# Return regression line for all groups in ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

I'm creating a scatterplot in `ggplot` where I am classifying the points based on company point. I would like to add a single trend line which shows the regression of all points. However, when I add `geom_smooth()` it adds a trend line for each class. How can I modify this so that I can show both the classes via the colors of the points and a single trend line that performs a regression of all data points regardless of class?

[image]

Here is some sample data:

```
ff<-as.data.frame(cbind(Energy_YearsToAchieve=c(5,10,15,13,10,8),Energy_Change=c(10,12,28,25,15,10), Sector_4C=c("A","B","C","A","B","B")))



ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change, color=Sector_4C)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work but not tested as no data was shared:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(Q18a, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change, color=Sector_4C)) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=1),color='violet')
```

Using new data:

```
#Code
ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change, color=Sector_4C)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))+
  geom_smooth(method = lm,se=F,aes(group=1),color='violet')
```

Output:

[image]

Following comments from **OP**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Code
G1 <- ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change, color=Sector_4C)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))+
  ggtitle('Trend by group')
G2 <- ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change, color=Sector_4C)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = lm,se=F,aes(group=1),color='violet')+
  ggtitle('Trend for all data')
#Merge
G1+G2+plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I just added sample data to the question.

Comment: Thank you. Right now its developing a trend line for each sector. I want one trend line that takes the trends of all points regardless of Sector.

Comment: yes I'm only looking to see the violet line in which case I believe  "geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))+" can be removed.

Comment: @Danny So you want one plot with the groups and other plot with only the one trend line merged into an individual plot. I will add that now.

Comment: @Danny I have added an update, let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color grouping to only be used in the point layer, then you need to remove the color mapping from the original ggplot(aes()) part and just put it in the point layer. Like this:

```
ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Sector_4C))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(group=Sector_4C))
```

And then if you want regression lines for the groups *and* and overall regression, then you do it like this:

```
ggplot(ff, aes(x=Energy_YearsToAchieve, y=Energy_Change)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Sector_4C))+
  # individual trend lines
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE,aes(color=Sector_4C))+
  # Overall trend line (no grouping or color mapping)
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE))
```